# Extrude along individual normals without changing the normal direction

Tags: normals, extrude

I have an insetted cube like this:

[image]

Their normals are quite, normal:

[image]

But after I "Extrude along Individual Normals", the faces change in direction:

[image]

How do I extrude them like this:

[image]

?

Comment: Use the S key (even thickness) while extruding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check *Offset Even* in the pop-up menu.

[image]

Comment: It works! But I wonder why it changes normal directions by default? I looked up the docs but only thing I found was https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shrink-fatten.html and it states "This tool moved selected vertices/edges/faces along their own normal (perpendicular to the face)".

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan Your OP shows Face Normals. The tool actually uses Vertex Normals, which is actually what you want, for _direction_, but you also sometimes want the _length_ of the extrusion to vary from vertex to vertex, to keep the new faces parallel to the old ones.  That's what 'Offset Even'  calculates.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thank you very much!